# Alter table add Boolean column with not null and default value 1 in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am adding one Boolean Column(status) into table(EMPLOYEE) in DB2 with below script,

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD status CHAR(1) not null DEFAULT '1' constraint EMPLOYEE_CK31 check (status in ('0','1'));
```

It is giving me error. Please let me know what is wrong in this script ?

Comment: This script worked.    ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD status CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1' not null  constraint EMPLOYEE_CK31 check (status in ('0','1'));

Answer (score 1):

This script worked after changing position of Default.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD status CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1' not null constraint EMPLOYEE_CK31 check (status in ('0','1'));
```

Comment: @Esperento57 -- your comment may be correct for Postgres, but it is completely wrong for DB2 -- database in question.